# "wrong attributetype" when using ldapadd

Tags: openldap

When attempting to load the following configuration

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcMirrorMode 
olcMirrorMode: TRUE
```

I get the following error:

```
root@box:~# ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f mirrormode.ldif 
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
ldapadd: wrong attributeType at line 4, entry "olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config"
```

It looks fine to me -- what's the problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a trailing space on on this line:

```
add: olcMirrorMode
```

Grrr!

Comment: How did you find out?

Comment: Good question! I don't think any diagnostic tools helped - I think I just noticed as I was examining the config, weeping. Sorry I can't be more specific, it was a while ago now.

Comment: Not sure if you use vim, but: https://github.com/itspriddle/vim-stripper

Comment: Thanks @seb !   @RelaXNow : to see if you have any `(export GREP_COLOR='0;41'; grep --col -Enm5 '\s+$' your.ldif)` to remove: `sed -ri 's,\s+$,,g' your.ldif`

Comment: A space in a line, which should be empty, is also fun.

Comment: @Boop: no need for the subshell or the `export` (just remove the semicolon): `GREP_COLOR='0;41' grep --col -Enm5 '\s+$' your.ldif`

Comment: For a plain text language, LDIF is surprisingly sensitive to whitespace issues.

Answer (score 2):

I've stepped on the same rake today, but there were no trailing spaces, there were another hidden joke.

My colleague have sent me a sample LDIF with a question, I tried to reproduce the problem he encountered by copying the text from the colleague's message. I've been struggling to understand what is wrong for an hour, before I understood that there was Unicode symbol `U+00A0` (`0xC2 0xA0`) instead of ASCII `SPACE` (`0x20`).

Thanks to vim and its syntax highlighting, vim was desperately trying to give me a clue: [image: vim tries to give a clue]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I missed to put a hyphen between multiple updates.

Wrong:

```
dn: cn=John Doe,ou=user,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: disabled
disabled: 0
add: activity
activity: INACTIVE
ldapmodify: wrong attributeType at line 5, entry "cn=John Doe,ou=user,dc=example,dc=com"
```

Correct:

```
dn: cn=John Doe,ou=user,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: disabled
disabled: 0
-
add: activity
activity: INACTIVE
```