# wrong attributeType while updating sambaPwdLastSet

Tags: openldap, ldif

I'm trying to reset the password expiry for a user (really set up a semi-automatic process for doing so) and it's making me cry:

server is openldap slapd: 2.4.28-1.1ubuntu4.2

```
$ ldapsearch -x -b dc=internal,dc=brazzers,dc=com uid=jenna sambaPwdLastSet sambaPwdMustChange
# jenna, People, internal.brazzers.com
dn: uid=jenna,ou=People,dc=internal,dc=brazzers,dc=com
sambaPwdLastSet: 1395420463
sambaPwdMustChange: 1398098896
```

Testing the output:

```
$ cat <<EOF
dn: uid=jenna,ou=People,dc=internal,dc=brazzers,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: sambaPwdLastSet 
sambaPwdLastSet: $(date -u +%s)
-
replace: sambaPwdMustChange
sambaPwdMustChange: $(date -u -d "+1 month" +%s)
-

EOF
```

Results in:

```
dn: uid=jenna,ou=People,dc=internal,dc=brazzers,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: sambaPwdLastSet 
sambaPwdLastSet: 1395421165
-
replace: sambaPwdMustChange
sambaPwdMustChange: 1398099565
-
```

OK, let's do this:

```
$ cat <<EOF | ldapmodify -D cn=admin,dc=internal,dc=brazzers,dc=com -W
dn: uid=jenna,ou=People,dc=internal,dc=brazzers,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: sambaPwdLastSet 
sambaPwdLastSet: $(date -u +%s)
-
replace: sambaPwdMustChange
sambaPwdMustChange: $(date -u -d "+1 month" +%s)
-

EOF
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldapmodify: wrong attributeType at line 4, entry "uid=jenna,ou=People,dc=internal,dc=brazzers,dc=com"
```

What? How could it be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARGH! Another attack of the trailing spaces!

I had a trailing space on `replace: sambaPwdLastSet` just like:

["wrong attributetype" when using ldapadd](https://serverfault.com/questions/578710/wrong-attributetype-when-using-ldapadd)